# Communication fails between Python 3 socket and QTcpsocket (c++)

Tags: c++, python-3.x, sockets, network-programming, qtcpsocket

Using Qt's QTcpsocket library and python 3's socket class currently. I have already gotten Qt's c++ fortune client / server example to build and run properly. However, it's for a client and server that are both C++. The requirement is that the server is running Python.

```
# Server.py


import socket

# ...
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("localhost", 45000)
sock.listen(1) # queuing up 1 request for now.

(clientsocket, address) = sock.accept() # waits until client connects.

chunk = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode() # client is now connect
print(chunk) #prints out message from client

msg = "Hello from the server"
msg = str.encode(msg)

# send the message back to the client
clientsocket.sendall(msg)
```

and

```
// Client.h

#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QtNetwork/QtNetwork>

class Client : public QObject {
     Q_OBJECT
public:
     Client();
     QTcpSocket *m_socket;
     QHostAddress m_serverAddr = QHostAddress("127.0.0.1");
     quint16 m_serverPort = 45000;
private:
     QDataStream m_dataStream;
     void testConnect();
};
#endif
```

and

```
// client.cpp

Client::Client() {
    m_socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    m_dataStream.setDevice(m_socket);
    m_dataStream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
    testConnect();

}

void Client::testConnect() {
        m_socket->abort(); // if m_socket is not already connected, this does nothing
        m_socket->connectToHost(m_serverAddr, m_serverPort);
        if (m_socket->waitForConnected(30000)) {
            qDebug() << "Connected to server...";
            m_socket->write("Hello server from client"); // is received!
            m_socket->waitForBytesWritten();
            m_socket->waitForReadyRead();
            qDebug() << "Reading: " << m_socket->bytesAvailable();
            m_dataStream.startTransaction();
            QString nextFortune;
            m_dataStream >> nextFortune;
            if (!m_dataStream.commitTransaction()) {
                qDebug() << "Read errors have occurred."; // prints when connected to python server. not desired behavior
                m_socket->close();  
                return;              

            }
            // This prints when running the Qt fortune c++ server, but not the python server (above).
            qDebug() << "No read errors occurred during read transactions.";
            qDebug() << nextFortune;
        }

}
```

What ends up happening is the server receives the message from the client without issue, but when the server attempts to send a reply with `clientsocket.sendall(msg)`, `m_dataStream.commitTransaction()` returns false. My initial instinct was that the encoding was wrong on the python side. Does QDataStream require a special encoding?

Documentation for QDataStream::commitTransaction():

> bool QDataStream::commitTransaction()
>
> Completes a read transaction. Returns `true` if no read errors have occurred 
>      during the transaction; otherwise returns `false`.

Also, after running, here is the output of the c++ client:

```
Connected to server...
Reading: 25
Read errors have occurred.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use `QDataStream` with operator `>>` you have to follow a serialization format. The call `QDataStream.setVersion()` select concrete format.

I've been able to found documentation only for [version 12](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html) (applies from `QDataStream::Qt_4_6` to `QDataStream::Qt_4_9`) and [version 13](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/datastreamformat.html) (`QDataStream::Qt_5_0`).

Version 12 and 13 have the same format for serialization of the QString:

> > If the string is null: 0xFFFFFFFF (quint32)
>
> > Otherwise: The string length in bytes (quint32) followed by the data in UTF-16

When you call `m_dataStream >> nextFortune` it expects the incoming data will be in the format described above.

The code in Python for send encoded `QString` can look like this:

```
import struct

msg = "Hello from the server".encode("utf-16be")
clientsocket.sendall(struct.pack(">I", len(msg)) + msg)
```

- `str.encode("utf-16be")` - encodes the string into UTF-16 with big-endian order
- `struct.pack(">I", len(msg))` - creates a 32-bit unsigned integer contains the length of the encoded string (`I`) in the big-endian orderd (`>`)

All data send to Qt's client are in big-endian order because it is implicit order which `QDataStream` uses.

I've tested the code with Qt 5.9 and serialization version `QDataStream::Qt_4_0`.

Comment: Thank you yes this enabled me to receive the message on the client properly. Thank you very much!